# Visual Basic Programming freezing when using do while loop

Tags: vb.net, basic

I have a VB project for school and it requires to use a loop. I'm trying to test it on my computer but each time I press "OK" on my program the program freezes and nothing is added onto the listbox. The only thing that appears new is the scroll bar on the listbox.

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    If total = 5 Then
        Do While counter < 5
            Marks.Items.Add(studentNumber)
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: How about increasing the counter inside your loop: `counter += 1` ;-). And how will `total` ever reach 5? Where is it defined? As this hasn't been part of the posted code, we can't give any suggestion of this may be part of your problem.

Comment: Oh jeez, I totally forgot about that. Fixed it, thanks. I had didn't include the rest of the code that included the value of total, but the problem is solved

Comment: Where are you incrementing/instantiating total?

Comment: That was an easy one and one that happens frequently when new to a programming language ;-). Do you mind if I create an answer so the question can be closed and doesn't remain open? Otherwise feel free to do so yourself.

Comment: Yeah you can create an answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but just accept @EstevaoLuis' answer below as it would have been my answer :-).

Comment: Where is `studentNumber` being set?  The code you have right now will add the same thing to `Marks.Items` 5 times, which probably isn't what you want to do.  You probably want to index something by `counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increment the counter

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0

Do While counter < 5
   Marks.Items.Add(studentNumber)
   counter += 1
Loop
```

If you want to add 5 items to your list, it is not necessary to use the If statement, because the while loop will be executed exactly 5 times

Comment: You could even use `counter += 1` instead of `counter = counter + 1` to shorten it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing the counter will fix the issue you're having in your do/while loop, but I'd also suggest you might be better suited just using a for loop, as this is exactly what they're made for.

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 5
    Marks.Items.Add(i) 'Assuming your counter == studentNumber.
Next
```